# Is there a reason my input isn't showing up?

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a budget application. I'm trying to get the number I'm inputting to be redirected to a p tag, but it's not showing up. I tested my code and I was able to get the text (Your Balance) to show up just fine, but the actual number that I'm taking from my input isn't showing up at all. I've tried a few things but can't seem to figure out why. Is it just not turning my input into a number?

html

```
<div class="enter-budget">
            <label for="budget">Please Enter Your Budget</label>
            <input type="number" id="input-balance">
            <button onclick="addBalance()">Calculate</button>
        </div>

            <div class="budget">
                <p>Budget</p>
                <p id="budget-amount"></p>
            </div>
```

javascript

```
let budget = document.getElementById("budget-amount");
let inputBalance = document.getElementById("input-balance").value;

const addBalance = () => {
    budget.textContent = `Your Balance: ${inputBalance}`
}
```

Comment: You need to get the value in the function. You're setting `inputBalance` once when the application first starts, before the user enters anything.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/jc8Lfeub/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a reference to the input value immediately, instead of when the `addBalance` method is called. You need to get the value when it's called.

```js
let budget = document.getElementById("budget-amount");
let inputBalance = document.getElementById("input-balance");

const addBalance = () => {
  let balance = inputBalance.value;
  budget.textContent = `Your Balance: ${balance}`
}
```

```html
<div class="enter-budget">
  <label for="budget">Please Enter Your Budget</label>
  <input type="number" id="input-balance">
  <button onclick="addBalance()">Calculate</button>
</div>

<div class="budget">
  <p>Budget</p>
  <p id="budget-amount"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I knew it would be something simple like that. Follow up question. Why is it that it's turning my input into a string? I've wrapped parseInt() around both balance and inputBalance but it still turns it into a string.